# Button is not working only in mac firefox

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

my button is not working only in mac firefox.. Below is the code

```
   <button class="col btn-change"><a href="/p/88" style="color: white;">Landscape</a></button>
```

But the below two code is working fine. in the above code , i am using my customize class btn-change for styling. i am using bootstrap col class , because i want to put 3-4 buttons together.

```
<a  href="/addproduct/143">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-family: Poppins">Order Sample Chevron</button>
      </a> 

<div id="buttonRollOverColour" class="col frameSelectBox"><a href="/p/414">Portrait</a></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Does clicking it not redirect? Does it redirect only when you click on the text inside the button?

Comment: Thanks james...below code is working but now button are not proportial   
   <div class="row">
      <div class='btn-group'>
      <a href="/p/89" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Portrait</button></a>
      <a href="/p/88" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Landscape</button></a>
      <a href="/p/87" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Square</button></a>
      </div>
</div>

Comment: The buttons are the width of whatever text is in them. You'll need to give them all `.col-md-4` or something like that (I'm no Bootstrap expert so you'd need to check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/) for more info).

Comment: Bootstrap works by splitting the page/divs/whatever into 12 columns. Therefore, if you set your page up correctly you should be able to have three things all taking up 4 columns and have them all evenly wide on the page.

Comment: @james, i did it (see questions) and it resolved my size issues with button. button it was not working on mac firefox. the code is in comment is modified and it's working on mac but now i have size issues...

Comment: In that case, your original question is resolved. You'd be best off asking another question about sizing issues if you can't figure it out for yourself as this is now getting off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

put below css and i hope it will work in mac,

```
#buttonRollOverColour>a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

It is because at some point mac screen don't support non button elements treated as button element, like you are using button and anchor tag inside it, you can also do it by using just a button tag instead.

Comment: thanks.. but below one is working...the top most is not working only, which has btn_change class

Comment: You have used an anchor tag inside it, i think that is the problem, just use button and it will work i hope.

Comment: If i will put my anchor outside my button it'll work fine on mac firefox... But i need to put 3 or 4 buttons together in a row. for that i am using col... than col class will not work. if i am using btn-group class for bind that button.. in that case button size are not equal..

Comment: share a snippet here.

Comment: <div class="row">
      <div class='btn-group'>
      <a href="/p/89" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Portrait</button></a>
      <a href="/p/88" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Landscape</button></a>
      <a href="/p/87" style="color: white;"><button class="btn-change">Square</button></a>
      </div>
</div>

Comment: you can give fixed with to those buttons.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer ? here is css .btn-change {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
     margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 100px #934391 inset;
}

Comment: .btn-change {width:100px;}
give maximum width of the button from that group

Comment: not a good idea... because no. of button and its content is not fixed... i need a solution which works on all and in each and every browser as well

Comment: you can get maximum size of a button and give it to all of them using jquery as well. This is the best one.

Comment: function getmaxwidth(){
    $(".btn-change").css({"width":"auto"});
    var width = $(".btn-change").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).width();
    }).get(),
    
    maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, width);
    $(".btn-change").css({"height":maxWidth });
}
getmaxwidth();
/* This will get the max width out of them and give it to all others.
also display:flex; will not let you change widths of those buttons, so remove display:flex;

Comment: it's still not working properly. i am using 2 or 3 rows. it sholud adjust according to available area https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/sm40exqz/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a` tag instead of button if you just want a link. And use `btn btn-primary|btn-light|...` styles of bootstrap to set `a` tag as button styles.

```
<a class="col btn btn-primary btn-change" href="/p/88">Landscape</a>
```